# Another Unorthodox Riddle

Tags: lateral-thinking

You are in a completely wooden room with no door, windows, or cracks. 
The only things in the room are yourself and a mirror. 
How would you escape?

Comment: Various versions of this riddle (and answer) can be found on a number of puzzling websites.  Could you provide attribution to where you got it from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one's a classic

> you look in the mirror, see what you saw, and use that "saw" to cut the wood to escape